Theodore Shifrin's Differential Geometry Exercise 1.3.7
The Question
Suppose $C$ is a convex simple closed plane curve with maximum curvature $\kappa_0$. Prove that the distance $d$ between any pair of parallel tangent lines of $C$ is at least $2 / \kappa_0$.
What I've Tried
If we denote $\theta(s)$ a function such that $T(s)=(\cos\theta(s),\sin\theta(s))$ and assume we can reparametrize $C$ by $\theta$, then the length $l$ of the curve satisfies
$$
l = \int_0^{2\pi} 1/\kappa(\theta)d\theta\geq 2\pi/\kappa_0,
$$
so $l/\pi\geq 2/\kappa_0$. If we can show that $d\geq l/\pi$ then we are done, but the inequality $d\geq l/\pi$ seems quite unlikely to be true.

Some sort of colloquial curse word maybe

Exercise 1.3.7, actually. ‍♂️ How do you talk about parallel tangent lines  of a convex curve with reference to the angle $\theta$? For specificity, start with the horizontal parallel tangents.

Parallel tagent lines tangent at the curve at $\alpha(s(\theta))$ and $\alpha(s(\theta+\pi))$, repectively. The distance between these two tangent lines should be $(\alpha(s(\theta+\pi)))-\alpha(s(\theta))\cdot N(s(\theta))$.

Great. So how do you get that as a $\theta$ integral?

Thank you for your help, I get it. If the minimum distance occurs at $\theta = \theta_0$, then we can write the distance as the integral $\int_{\theta_0}^{\theta_0 + \pi} \alpha'(s(\theta)) s'(\theta) \cdot N(s(\theta_0)) d\theta$, which eventually $\geq \frac{1}{\kappa_0} \int_0^\pi \sin(\theta)d\theta$.

Well done. You might want to write a complete answer to the question.
